# AngularJs Patch Request

Tags: angularjs, httprequest

I am trying to update data through my API using http Patch method. But i am getting a Bad Response or Internal Server Error.

Here is my JSON call:

```
$http.patch(baseUrl + '/users/' + currentUserEmail,data).success(success).error(error)
```

Comment: My API PATCH Method needs an IF-Match header but isn't it added automatically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add needed headers using the optional 3rd params of $http.patch :

```
var config = {headers: {'IF-Match': 'your-data'}};
$http.patch(baseUrl + '/users/' + currentUserEmail,data, config).success(success).error(error)
```

The [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#usage) provides info about custom config options.

If you wish to add custom headers to every request automatically you can use the [$http interceptor](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#interceptors) :

```
angular.module('app').factory('HttpInterceptor', function () {
  return {
    request: function (config) {
      if (config.method === 'PATCH')
         config.headers['IF-Match'] = 'your-data';
      return config;
    }
  };
});

angular.module('app').config(['$httpProvider', '$resourceProvider', function ($httpProvider, $resourceProvider) {
    // Add the interceptor to the $httpProvider to intercept http calls
    $httpProvider.interceptors.push('HttpInterceptor');
}])
```

EDIT: to answer your comment about how to get info from GET request.
In the http interceptor, you can intercept response as well :

```
angular.module('app').factory('HttpInterceptor', function () {
 var etag = null;
  return {
    request: function (config) {
      if (config.method === 'PATCH')
         config.headers['IF-Match'] = etag;
      return config;
    },
   response: function (response) {
      if (response.config.method === 'GET')
          etag = reponse.config.headers['e-tag'];
        // Return the response or promise.
      return response || $q.when(response);
    },
  };
});
```

Comment: How to get the If-Match Data, as it should be equal to E-Tag value from a Get Response? How can i read that value?

Comment: Print the config object in the http interceptor, it contains everything you need

Comment: I am able to add the If-Match value to the request, but still not clear about how to get the value from the response of a get method

Comment: I edited my answer (with pseudo code, I have not test it)

Comment: Yes, i have changed config to response in the response function, but all i am getting is NULL. I think the response function is properly getting the response form the server. Any ideas?

Comment: What is null ? The response object contains the config object so you can do response.config.headers

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93575/discussion-between-hunzaboy-and-alexandre-nucera).

Comment: There is a problem with this solution. The etag of every request is saved in it. Eg. there is etag for getting the css files, html files etc. So i wanted to get the etag when the user does a GET method to get information of user form the API

Comment: the config object contains other properties such as the url, so modify the if condition in the request function to match your needs (i.e : saving the etag only when you acces a specific url)